# Arithmetic on Vectors Clojure

Tags: vector, clojure

I am trying to run some arithmetic on Vectors in clojure, but i cannot seem to get any of it to work. I have these vectors....

```
locs -  [[3 3] [5 5] [1 1] [2 2]]
tlocs - [[2 2] [4 5]]
rng -   [2]
```

What i want to do is iterate or recur over locs and take the first set of numbers and check it against the first set of tlocs and see if they are within the range of the data in rng.  So for example of the first go round it would check that [3 3] is within range [2 2] which it is, then check if [5 5] is in range of [2 2] which it isnt.  Once i have done all of the locs values against the first set in tlocs it will go again but using [4 5] for the comparing.

Can anyone help me write a function that does this??

I tried doing something like this but it doesnt work and doesnt look right either

```
(defn check [locs tlocs rng 0]
 (loop [locs tlocs rng 0]
  (<= (first t (first d)r)
   (recur (rest locs) (inc index)))))
```

Comment: Can you specify what it means "in range"? And why `[3 3]` within the range `[2 2]` and `[5 1]` isn't? If function `check`: 0 is not allowed in argument list. `loop` looks very dodgy: you shadow `locs` and `rng` arguments.

Comment: in range as in, distances so metres for example the maximum range is 2 metres, [3 3] is only 1 metre away from [2 2]. But [5 5], 5 - 2 = 3  so out of range as it exceeds 2. But it is in range of the 2nd tloc [4 5]

Comment: And what do you want the result to be?

Comment: just true of false really, im trying to represent a graph and see if its connected or in range. so the [1 2] are locations on the graph and i want to see if they are in range

Comment: @Freeman Wait, is the `[2 2]` a location on the graph? Or is it a range? From your previous comment, it sounds like it might be both? How is that useful?

Comment: Its a location but the range (rng) is the range which is 2,  so i am checking if [3 3] is in range of [2 2], with the range being [2]

Comment: @Freeman So you want the function to return `true` *only* if every one of `locs` is in range of every one of `tlocs`, otherwise return `false`?

Comment: Yeah basically so that i would know if they were all connected or in range.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way you could write it:

```
(defn in-range? [loc tloc rng]
  (every? #(<= % rng) (map (comp #(Math/abs %) -) loc tloc)))

(defn check [locs tlocs rng]
  (every? true? (for [tloc tlocs loc locs] (in-range? loc tloc rng))))
```

So, for every possible pairing of a value in `tlocs` and a value in `locs`, check if the `loc` is in range of the `tloc`. Then return `false` if any of those range checks return `false`.

Example:

```
(def locs [[3 3] [5 5] [1 1] [2 2]])
(def tlocs [[2 2] [4 5]])
(def rng 2)

(check locs tlocs rng) ;=> false
```

However, I'm still not really sure if this is what you want. `in-range?` doesn't check the Euclidean distance between `loc` and `tloc`; it just ensures that the absolute difference between their coordinates in each dimension is less than `rng`.

Comment: Yeah thats what im after, i dont think i explained very well. I am after coordinates in each dimension being less than the range. Just making sure they are not too far away